# Protecting multiple ranges for multiple groups/users in a single Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, password-protection, protected, named-ranges

I am aware of how to set editable ranges for users to modify certain ranges in a worksheet.  However, I have been unable to set up two separate ranges with separate permissions.  Here's what I want to accomplish:

Range #1: Editable to all users at all times (when sheet is protected or unprotected)

Range #2: Editable to a selected group of user(s), requiring a password to unlock and edit -- this is restricted content that only certain individuals can change

Rest of worksheet: Locked to all except the developer of the worksheet with another password -- want to keep the worksheet "dummy-proof" functionally

I tried creating multiple "allow edit" ranges but for Range #2 I can only block specifically listed users from editing this range.  I want to block ALL EXCEPT specifically listed users.  Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: You're aware that worksheet protection is a joke yes?

Comment: Quick note: Range #2 can require or not require permitted users to enter a password, as long as "all other users" definitely need a password to modify it.

Comment: It's not critical info.  Could care less who reads it (its supposed to be read).  I just want to reasonably dummy proof others from changing it

Comment: So those users are too dumb to spend 10 min to crack it? In that case, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Untested but here is a [website](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-enable-excel-cell-range-editing-by-certain-.html) which seems to be describing exactly what you want